# Equalizing of powers in power series solution method

Tags: power-series

I have reached to the following equation using power series solution method 
$$
\sum_{i=0}^p(i+1)\,a_i\,r^{i+1}+\sum_{i=0}^pa_i\,r^i+\sum_{i=0}^p(i+2)\,a_i\,r^{i-1}=0
$$
I really don't know what should I do to equalize the powers. Do limits of summations change during this process? and if yes, how?

Comment: The first and third sums are known as "Arithmetico–geometric sequences". https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetico%E2%80%93geometric_sequence. The second sum is a geometric series.

Comment: Should the three $a_i$'s all be the same?  Yes, you need to pick different terms from each sum to get matching powers of $r$.  The right sum is the only one that has an $r^{-1}$ term, which is when its $i=0$.  That tells you $a_0$ in the third is zero.  Then you have two $r^0$ terms, then three of each power up to $r^{p-1}$

Comment: @automaticallyGenerated:  not if the $a_i$ vary.  That will spoil it.

Comment: Silly mistake on my part - I didn't see that there was a subscript on the $a$.

Comment: sorry, but I didn't get your means, please more explain

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\sum_{i=0}^p(i+1)\,a_i\,r^{i+1}+\sum_{i=0}^pa_i\,r^i+\sum_{i=0}^p(i+2)\,a_i\,r^{i-1}=0$$

For each term, make the power equal to $k$ to get the required $i$.

So, for the first term, $i+1=k\implies i=k-1$, for the second $i=k$ and for the third, $i-1=k\implies i=k+1$.

Rewriting
$$ka_{k-1}+a_k+(k+3)a_{k+1}=0$$

**Edit**

I made a mistake assuming that the summations are going to $\infty$. Since, from comments, this is not the case, we must be more careful.

The terms will be
$$\frac{2a_0} x+(a_0+3a_1)+\sum_{k=1}^{p-1}\big(ka_{k-1}+a_k+(k+3)a_{k+1}\big)x^k+(pa_{p-1}+a_p)x^{p}+(p+1)a_p x^{p+1}$$ But this then implies $a_p=a_{p-1}=0$ as well as $a_0=a_1=0$. Then, this reduces the problem of
$$\sum_{i=1}^{p-2}(i+1)\,a_i\,r^{i+1}+\sum_{i=1}^{p-2} a_i\,r^i+\sum_{i=1}^{p-2}(i+2)\,a_i\,r^{i-1}=0$$ to which apply
$$ka_{k-1}+a_k+(k+3)a_{k+1}=0$$

Comment: How about limits of summations?

Comment: @Wisdom. We do not care about them; I assumed that all summations go to $\infty$. If $p$ is not, then you are right and my solution is not complete.

Comment: exactly, $p$ is not $\infty$

Comment: @Wisdom. Then, I made a mistake ! See my edit.

Comment: why power $p$ has appeared?

Comment: @Wisdom. Look at the first and second summation for $x^p$ and  at the first for $x^{p+1}$

Answer (score 1):

> We shift indices of  the series to easily collect coefficients of equal powers of $r$. We obtain for integral  $p\geq        0$:
>   \begin{align*}
> \sum_{i=0}^p&(i+1)a_ir^{i+1}+\sum_{i=0}^pa_ir^i+\sum_{i=0}^p(i+2)a_ir^{i-1}\\
> &=\sum_{i=1}^{p+1}ia_{i-1}r^i+\sum_{i=0}^pa_ir^i+\sum_{i=-1}^{p-1}(i+3)a_{i+1}r^i=0\tag{1}
> \end{align*}

In (1) we shift the index of the left-most sum by $+1$ and of the right-most sum  by $-1$ to obtain equal powers $r^i$.

> We obtain by collecting coefficients of equal powers from (1):
>   \begin{align*}
> \sum_{i=-1}^{-1}&(i+3)a_{i+1}r^i+\sum_{i=0}^0a_ir^i+\sum_{i=1}^1ia_{i-1}r^i\tag{$p=0$}\\
> &=2a_0\frac{1}{r}+a_0+a_0r\\
> &=0\\
> \sum_{i=-1}^{0}&(i+3)a_{i+1}r^i+\sum_{i=0}^1a_ir^i+\sum_{i=1}^2ia_{i-1}r^i\tag{$p=1$}\\
> &=\left(2a_0\frac{1}{r}+3a_0\right)+\left(a_0+a_1r\right)+\left(a_0r+2a_1r^2\right)\\
> &=2a_0\frac{1}{r}+4a_0+(a_0+a_1)r+2a_1r^2\\
> &=0\\
> \sum_{i=-1}^{p-1}&(i+3)a_{i+1}r^i+\sum_{i=0}^pa_ir^i+\sum_{i=1}^{p+1}ia_{i-1}r^i\tag{$p\geq  2$}\\
> &=2a_0\frac{1}{r}+3a_1+a_0+\sum_{i=1}^{p-1}\left(ia_{i-1}+a_i+(i+3)a_{i+1}\right)r^i\\
> &\qquad+\left((p-1)a_{p-1}+a_{p}\right)r^p+(p+1)a_pr^{p+1}\\
> &=0
> \end{align*}
>
> We observe that only the trivial solutions $a_j=0, j\geq 0$ occur for each $p\geq 0$.

In  the case $p\geq 2$ we separated the terms  with $i\in\{-1,0,p,p+1\}$ and collected the other terms within one sum.